# mapping from S to T and T to U such that S to U is injective.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let S, T, U be three non-void sets and $f : S \rightarrow T, g : T \rightarrow U$ be so that $g o f : S \rightarrow U$ is injective. Then should $g$ and $f$ both be injective?

I think that $g$ should be injective but I'm not sure about $f$

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around: $g\circ f$ being injective implies that $f$ is injective. Since if $f(x)=f(y),$ then $g(f(x))=g(f(y)),$ which, by assumption, implies $x=y$.

To see that $g$ need not be injective, consider $f:[0,1]\to [-1,1]$ given by $x\mapsto x$ and $g:[-1,1]\to [0,1]$ given by $x\mapsto |x|$, then $g\circ f(x)=x$, which is clearly injective, but $g$ is not injective since $g(-1)=g(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

No, $g$ need not be injective, but $f$ does.

Indeed, if $f(a)=f(b)$, then $g(f(a))=g(f(b))$; because $g\circ f$ is injective, we conclude that $a=b$.

For a counterexample, consider $S=\{0\}$, $T=\{1,2\}$ and $U=\{3\}$. Define $f(0)=1$ and let $g$ be the unique map $g\colon T\to U$. Then $g\circ f$ is injective (because the domain has a single element), but $g$ isn't.

---

The same example shows that if $g\circ f$ is surjective, then $f$ need not be surjective.